# Can dropout layers not influence LSTM training?

Tags: neural-networks, keras, long-short-term-memory, dropout, regularization

I am working on a project that requires time-series prediction (regression) and I use LSTM network with first 1D conv layer in Keras/TF-gpu as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=60, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], len(features_used)), kernel_size=5, padding='causal', strides=1))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units=128))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
```

As an effect my model is clearly overfitting:
[image]

So I decided to add dropout layers, first I added layers with 0.1, 0.3 and finally 0.5 rate:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=60, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], len(features_used)), kernel_size=5, padding='causal', strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(units=128))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
```

However I think that it has no effect on the network learning process, even though 0.5 is quite large dropout rate:
[image]

Is this possible that dropout has little/no effect on a training process of LSTM  or maybe I do something wrong here?

[EDIT] Adding plots of my TS, general and zoomed in view.
[image]
[image]

I also want to add that the time of training increases just a bit (i.e. from 1540 to 1620 seconds) when I add the dropout layers.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points:

1. Have you firstly scaled your data, e.g. using **MinMaxScaler**? This could be one reason why your loss readings remain high.
2. Additionally, consider that while Dropout can be useful for reducing overfitting, it is not necessarily a panacea.

Let's take an example of using LSTM to forecast fluctuations in weekly hotel cancellations.

**Model without Dropout**

```
# Generate LSTM network
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, previous)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history=model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Over 20 epochs, the model achieves a validation loss of **0.0267** without Dropout.

[image: loss without dropout]

**Model with Dropout**

```
# Generate LSTM network
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, previous)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history=model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

However, validation loss is slightly higher with Dropout at **0.0428**.

[image: loss with dropout]

3. Make sure you have specified the loss function correctly. If you are forecasting a time series, then you are most likely working with interval data. Therefore, **mean_squared_error** is an appropriate loss function as one is trying to estimate the deviation between the predicted and actual values.

As a counterexample, **binary_crossentropy** would not be suitable as the time series is not a classification set. However, misspecifying the loss function is a common error. Therefore, you also want to make sure you are using the appropriate loss function and then work from there.

Comment: 1. Yes, I scale data with StandardScaler
2. This might be the answer, but why this happens? What's the remedy?
3. Yes, I use MSE as a loss function

Comment: Can you please include a plot of the time series itself (if that's possible)? It will be easier for me to answer if I know the structure of the series.

Comment: I added plots to the main question :)

Comment: In your second graph, we can see a clear trend in the time series. From my experience, LSTMs don't tend to work very well with trend data. Here is an example: https://towardsdatascience.com/are-lstms-always-effective-at-time-series-analysis-a-case-study-of-oil-prices-97644f716a1c